# Copy data from Postgres to SQLServer using SSIS with date parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, ssis, etl

I want to copy data from postgres DB to SQL Server using SSIS. I already did using Data flow and succeed. But this time I want to use parameter date in query.

For the example :

```
SELECT * 
FROM dw_sales 
WHERE transaction_date >= current_date - 7
```

I want to replace current_date - 7 using parameter @fromdate in SSIS, so the query will be

```
SELECT * 
FROM dw_sales 
WHERE transaction_date >= current_date - @fromdate
```

I know how to do it if I am using a stored procedure in SQL Server, but when I copy data from Postgres, I don't know how.

[image: DataFlow]

[image: Data Query]

Can you guys help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Within the OLE DB Source, use SQL Command option and use `?` mark to add a parameter:

```sql
SELECT * FROM dw_sales WHERE transaction_date >= current_date - ?
```

Then click on the **Parameters** button to map this parameter to a SSIS variable:

[image]